# Torch filter multidimensional tensor by start and end values

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, tensor

I have a list of sentences and I am looking to extract contents between two items.
If the start or end item does not exist, I want it to return a row with padding only.
I already have the sentences tokenized and padded with 0 to a fixed length.

I figured a way to do this using for loops, but it is extremely slow, so would like to
know what is the best way to solve this, probably by using tensor operations.

```
import torch
start_value, end_value = 4,9

data = torch.tensor([
[3,4,7,8,9,2,0,0,0,0], 
[1,5,3,4,7,2,8,9,10,0],
[3,4,7,8,10,0,0,0,0,0], # does not contain end value
[3,7,5,9,2,0,0,0,0,0], # does not contain start value
])

# expected output
[
[7,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[7,2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
]
# or 
[
[0,0,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,7,2,8,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
]
```

The current solution that I have, which uses a for loop. It does not produce a symmetric array like I want in the expected output.

```
def _get_part_from_tokens(
    self,
    data: torch.Tensor,
    s_id: int,
    e_id: int,
) -> list[str]:
    input_ids = []
    for row in data:
        try:
            s_index = (row == s_id).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0][0]
            e_index = (row == e_id).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0][0]
        except IndexError:
            input_ids.append(torch.tensor([]))
            continue
        if s_index is None or e_index is None or s_index > e_index:
            input_ids.append(torch.tensor([]))
            continue
        ind = torch.arange(s_index + 1, e_index)
        input_ids.append(row.index_select(0, ind))
    return input_ids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible loop-free approach is this:

```py
import torch

# using the provided sample data
start_value, end_value = 4,9
data = torch.tensor([
    [3,4,7,8,9,2,0,0,0,0], 
    [1,5,3,4,7,2,8,9,10,0],
    [3,4,7,8,10,0,0,0,0,0], # does not contain end value
    [3,7,5,9,2,0,0,0,0,0], # does not contain start value
    [3,7,5,8,2,0,0,0,0,0], # does not contain start or end value
])
```

First, check which rows contain only a `start_value` or an `end_value` and fill these rows with `0`.

```py
# fill 'invalid' rows with 0
starts = (data == start_value)
ends = (data == end_value)
invalid = ((starts.sum(axis=1) - ends.sum(axis=1)) != 0)
data[invalid] = 0
```

Then set the values up to (and including) the `start_value` and after (and including) the `end_value` to `0` in each row. This step targets mainly the 'valid' rows. Nevertheless, all other rows will (again) be overwritten with zeros.

```py
# set values in the start and end of 'valid rows' to 0
row_length = data.shape[1]
start_idx = starts.long().argmax(axis=1)
start_mask = (start_idx[:,None] - torch.arange(row_length))>=0
data[start_mask] = 0
end_idx = row_length - ends.long().argmax(axis=1)
end_mask = (end_idx[:,None] + torch.arange(row_length))>=row_length 
data[end_mask] = 0
```

*Note:* This works also, if a row contains neither a `start_value` nor an `end_value` (I added such a row to the sample data). Still, there are many more edge cases that one could think of (e.g. multiple start and end values in one row, start value after end value, ...). Not sure if they are of relevance for the specific problem.

---

**Comparison of execution time**

Using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) and randomly generated data to compare the execution time of the different approaches suggests, that the approach without loops is considerably faster than the approach from the question. If the data is converted to numpy first and converted back to Pytorch afterwards some further (very minor) time savings are possible.

[image: comparing execution time of approach with and without loop]

Each dot (execution time) in the plot is the minimum value of 3 trials each with 100 repetitions.

Comment: unfortunately this turned out to be slower than the for loop version. I have updated the question and included the for loop version of my code.

Comment: I made a small comparison of the execution times of the different approaches with random data. For me, it seems that the approach suggested in the answer is indeed faster... Hard to say, why we come to such different evaluations of the approaches. Probably the 'original' data extracted from text is quite different from the randomly generated data. The comparison also neglects, that the output of the two approaches is different (2d tensor vs list of tensors) and at least one of them needs further preparations. But still...

Comment: thank you very much for providing the solution and the execution time graph. I was surprised when I saw that the loop free version was not faster. As you pointed out, there must be something going on in the original data or some other point in my code which might be causing the problem. I will take a look into that and thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

this is my attempt at improving @rosa b. algorithm.
Could you try this:

```py
def function1(
    data: torch.Tensor,
    start_value: int,
    end_value: int,
):

    # fill 'invalid' rows with 0
    row_length = data.shape[1]
    starts = (data == start_value)
    ends = (data == end_value)

    invalid = ((starts.sum(axis=1) - ends.sum(axis=1)) != 0)
    data[invalid] = 0

    valid_ind = torch.where(torch.logical_not(invalid))

    # set values in the start and end of 'valid rows' to 0
    arange_arr = torch.arange(row_length)
    start_idx = starts.long()[valid_ind].argmax(axis=1)

    start_mask = (start_idx[:, None] - arange_arr) >= 0

    end_idx = row_length - ends.long()[valid_ind].argmax(axis=1)
    end_mask = (end_idx[:, None] + arange_arr) >= row_length

    mask = torch.logical_or(start_mask, end_mask)
    tmp = data[valid_ind]
    tmp.masked_fill_(mask, 0)
    data[valid_ind] = tmp

    return data
```

The main idea is I think the list of valid indexes is small. Therefore, we could skip many computations. I make some other minor updates so it should be slightly faster.

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation to make a comment).

Comment: thank you for your input, i can see the updates you have done and it should be faster. I will incorporate your ideas.